# the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that returns `Result` or `Option

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm learning rust and trying to scrape a random site by sending some POST data, and I'm getting a bunch of errors like:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)

37  | |     let text = res.text().await?;
    | |                                ^ cannot use the `?` operator in an async block that returns `()`
```

The code is below. I've gone through the docs multiple times, but I'm returning a Result<> so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
use std::sync::Arc;


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    use reqwest::{cookie::Jar, Url};
    use reqwest::header;

    let mut headers = header::HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert("User-Agent", header::HeaderValue::from_static("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"));
    headers.insert("Content-Type", header::HeaderValue::from_static("application/json"));
    
    let cookie = "cookies";

    let jar = Jar::default();
    let cookie_url = "https://url.com/".parse::<Url>()?;
    jar.add_cookie_str(cookie, &cookie_url);

    let body = String::from("post body"); 

    let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
    .default_headers(headers)
    .cookie_store(true)
    .cookie_provider(Arc::new(jar))
    .build()?;

    let path = "https://long_url.com".parse::<Url>()?;

    let res = client
        .post(path)
        .body(body)
        .send()
        .await?;

    let text = res.text().await?;
    println!("{}", text);

    Ok(());
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have an extra semicolon at the end of your `main` function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The message is a bit confusing because of the transformations being performed, you may want to report this on the bug tracker, but do note the wording:

> ^ cannot use the `?` operator in **an async block** that returns `()`

It uses the word "block", not function. Because this is really a cascading error: behind the scenes, an `async` function is converted into a state machines where each `await` is a "yield point" between blocks of code, so

```rust
let res = client
        .post(path)
        .body(body)
        .send()
        .await?;

    let text = res.text().await?;
    println!("{}", text);

    Ok(());
```

can be thought of along the lines of (this is not the actual transformation, if you want an actual deconstruction Jon Gjengset has an extensive video on the subject)

```rust
let future = async {
    client.post(path).body(body).send()
};
yield future;
let future = async {
    let res = future.value()?;
    res.text()
};
yield future;
let future = async {
    let text = future.value()?;
    println!("{}", text);

    Ok(());
};
return future;
```

Note the last expression of the last block, this is where the problem occurs: it's `Ok(());`.

The trailing semicolon will "suppress" the expression's normal value and result in a `()`, not `Result<...>`, hence a type incompatibility and the error you see: the return value *of the block* is incoherent.

At the end of the pile of async block errors, the compiler actually shows the "source" error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 | async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  |          ----      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Result`, found `()`
  |          |
  |          implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
  |
  = note:   expected enum `Result<(), Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
          found unit type `()`
```

and if you look at the entire "async block" error, it takes care to show the errorneous `Ok(());` *every time*:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
   --> src/lib.rs:19:55
    |
6   |   async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    |  ___________________________________________________________-
7   | |     println!("Hello, world!");
8   | |
9   | |     use reqwest::{cookie::Jar, Url};
...   |
19  | |     let cookie_url = "https://url.com/".parse::<Url>()?;
    | |                                                       ^ cannot use the `?` operator in an async block that returns `()`
...   |
41  | |     Ok(());
42  | | }
    | |_- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
    |
    = help: the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, url::parser::ParseError>>` is not implemented for `()`
note: required by `from_residual`
```

Comment: `Ok(())` _is_ a `Result<(), …>`. The problem is with the extra semicolon at the end of the `main` function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant but it's true that it's not really clear. I'll edit the relevant bit.

Comment: thank you! would have never figured this out

Answer (score 2):

When I try your code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a0fd46643fd098348df4d69a8498635), I get a lot of errors like yours, but I also get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
5 | async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  |          ----      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Result`, found `()`
  |          |
  |          implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
  |
  = note:   expected enum `Result<(), Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
          found unit type `()`
```

This is caused by the extra semicolon at the end of your `main` function. Removing this semicolon fixes all errors:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    use reqwest::{cookie::Jar, Url};
    use reqwest::header;

    let mut headers = header::HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert("User-Agent", header::HeaderValue::from_static("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"));
    headers.insert("Content-Type", header::HeaderValue::from_static("application/json"));
    
    let cookie = "cookies";

    let jar = Jar::default();
    let cookie_url = "https://url.com/".parse::<Url>()?;
    jar.add_cookie_str(cookie, &cookie_url);

    let body = String::from("post body"); 

    let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
    .default_headers(headers)
    .cookie_store(true)
    .cookie_provider(Arc::new(jar))
    .build()?;

    let path = "https://long_url.com".parse::<Url>()?;

    let res = client
        .post(path)
        .body(body)
        .send()
        .await?;

    let text = res.text().await?;
    println!("{}", text);

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a6b20af7126983ea04f301d933d6777)